# passing json string from php to python

Tags: php, python, input, passthru

I am trying to call a python script within a php script. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to pass an input through to the python script.
The code I am using is as follows:

```
$input = '[{"item": "item1"}, {"item": "item2"}, {"item": "item3"}]';
$output = passthru("/usr/bin/python3.5 /path/python_script.py $input");
```

The output in python is a list that is created by splitting the string by spaces i.e. ' ' whilst removing the the quotation marks:

```
['/path/python_script.py', '[{item:', 'item1},', '{item:', 'item2},', '{item:', 'item3}]']
```

What would be the most straight-forward way to pass a json string through to python?

Comment: Can you clarify what actually isn't working?

Comment: I would like to have the input passed through as a complete string, not split in a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve your problem, you need to pass the json as a string.
In your PHP it's a string, but the moment you call passthru, it's converted to command line. So it calls python like this:

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 /path/python_script.py [{"item": "item1"}, {"item": "item2"}, {"item": "item3"}]
```

Python indeed splits it on space and sees each part as an argument. The solution would be to wrap it in a string for passthru if possible:

```
$output = passthru("/usr/bin/python3.5 /path/python_script.py '$input'");
```

Then in your python script you can use json.loads as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18006814/1291498).

If you cannot wrap it in string, you could do this in yout python script to put it all together manually:

```
''.join(sys.argv[1:]) # leaving out the first index, filename.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use python script as a CGI script, and pass the arguments to Python CGI script just like you pass parameters to an API or URL.

Python CGI Tutorial : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm