# Passing json-like object into python2.7 as an argument fails

Tags: json, python-2.7

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006161/how-to-pass-dictionary-as-command-line-argument-to-python-script) solution, and the highest ranking solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707558/json-valueerror-expecting-property-name-line-1-column-2-char-1) and none work.

I have a java automation script that I need to run a python script remotely while giving it a JSON object to treat as a dictionary.

JSON object as the java give it: 
{\'oracle_11gd.pcap\': \'19.0.0.10\' ,\'oracle_11g_also.pcap\': \'19.0.0.17\'}

The object is actually longer, I just gave a sample here.

The solution each fails, and I suspect it's because of the backslashes, but I can't even bring it in as a string to replace the backslash with nothing, like this:

```
data = str(sys.argv[1])
    data = data.replace("\\", "")

    transportDictionary = ast.literal_eval(data)
```

I tried just

```
data = sys.argv[1]
```

Also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to echo the JSON into a JSON file on the remote machine where the python runs, while using sed to replace the backslashes and single quotes into nothing and double quotes. Like so:

```
echo {\'oracle_11gd.pcap\': \'19.0.0.10\' ,\'oracle_11g_also.pcap\': \'19.0.0.17\'} sed 's|\\||g' | sed 's|\\x27|\"|g' > pcaps.json
```

Then, in the python, I read the file and json.load like so:

```
import json

.
.
.

with open(directory + 'pcaps.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    transportDictionary = eval(json.dumps(data))
```