# Pass dict as an argument over SSH to Python script

Tags: python, ssh, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass dict arguments using the `ssh` command via the `os` module:

```
os.system(f'ssh remote_host python -u - {dict1} {dict2} < local_script.py')
```

I am getting an error:

> sh:line:0 syntax error near unexpected token ('

What is the right syntax to pass dict as an argument?

If I pass string instead of dict, it works fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you should convert your dicts to json strings.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, i tried like this, in dict "datatime" object is available and it is not able to serialize in json

Comment: For datetime problem, convert ```datetime``` object to string using ```strftime```

Comment: Thank you! as suggested i used strftime and later i used strptime to get datetime object

Comment: Related question: [How to pass dictionary as command line argument to Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18006161/850848)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use json and urlencode.

```
import urllib.parse
import json
dict1_j = urllib.parse.quote(json.dumps(dict1))
dict2_j = urllib.parse.quote(json.dumps(dict2))
os.system(f'ssh remote_host python -u - {dict1_j} {dict2_j} < local_script.py')
```

And you can use urldecode and json pharse to decode this in local_script.py

```
import json 
import urllib.parse 
dict1 = json.loads(urllib.parse.unquote(sys.argv[1])) 
dict2 = json.loads(urllib.parse.unquote(sys.argv[2]))
```